# Post two textfields in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to fill two textfields in a page I loaded in UIWebView. I have been busy with NSMutableRequests.
My code:

```
// webView is an object of UIWebView

// This is my ViewDidLoad Function

NSString *cijferString = @"leerling.degoudsewaarden.nl";
NSURL *cijferURL = [NSURL URLWithString:cijferString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLReuqest requestWithURL:cijferURL];

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wu_loginname=%@&wu_password=%@", @"username", @"password"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

All I want is submit my username and password to the webpage. It will automatically load the next page.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate and use the ASIHTTPRequest framework, it makes sending POST requests very easy and in general is a great framework for doing RESTful HTTP stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I already came across their site, I will look into it!